# Can’t log into TimeMachine on OpenWrt router with AFP Netatalk

Tags: router, openwrt, afp, netatalk

I've put OpenWrt on a router (TP-Link TL-WR902AC v3) hoping to set it up with [AFP Netatalk](http://netatalk.sourceforge.net/3.0/htmldocs/afp.conf.5.html) and use it as a mobile backup.

I’ve carefully followed the [AFP Netatalk instructions](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/services/nas/netatalk_configuration) and everything looks right until I attempt to set the drive as my TimeMachine backup. I can select the drive and am then prompted for login credentials. However after a few seconds I get an error alert.

> Time Machine can’t connect to the backup disk.
>
> There was an error authenticating with the provided username or password.

[image: TimeMachine authentication error.]

The AFP log shows the following.

```
Apr 24 10:20:10.232125 cnid_metad[2554] {cnid_metad.c:509} (note:AFPDaemon): CNID Server listening on localhost:4700
Apr 24 10:20:10.274105 afpd[2553] {afp_config.c:174} (note:AFPDaemon): Netatalk AFP/TCP listening on interface br-lan with address 192.168.7.3:548
Apr 24 10:20:10.274920 afpd[2553] {afp_config.c:174} (note:AFPDaemon): Netatalk AFP/TCP listening on interface br-lan with address fdea:9d0f:bd16::1:548
Apr 24 10:20:10.275973 afpd[2553] {afp_config.c:174} (note:AFPDaemon): Netatalk AFP/TCP listening on interface br-lan with address fe80::da47:32ff:febf:a64e:548
Apr 24 10:21:18.928836 afpd[2594] {auth.c:235} (note:AFPDaemon): Login by pedro (AFP3.4)
Apr 24 10:21:18.943576 afpd[2594] {auth.c:804} (note:AFPDaemon): AFP logout by pedro
Apr 24 10:21:18.945730 afpd[2594] {dsi_stream.c:504} (error:DSI): dsi_stream_read: len:0, unexpected EOF
Apr 24 10:21:18.946191 afpd[2594] {afp_dsi.c:517} (note:AFPDaemon): afp_over_dsi: client logged out, terminating DSI session
Apr 24 10:21:18.946878 afpd[2594] {afp_dsi.c:108} (note:AFPDaemon): AFP statistics: 0.60 KB read, 0.44 KB written
```

It appears it’s accepting my login then immediately logging me out again.

I am using a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014) running macOS Big Sur (11.2.3).

UPDATE: It does work if I take the undesirable step of setting 777 permissions on the Backups folder.

Comment: Odd. Have you looked at [this thread on Ars Technica](https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=1305987)? Did you make sure that the `afp.conf` file has the `path` set in `[Backups]`?

Comment: Path set `path = /mnt/sdb2/Backups` as per instructions I followed. From the log, that thread seems to have the same problem as me, but unless it's in using `net\mdnsresponder` no solution. I'll look into that option.